# Binding ListView inside a GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'd like to create a calendar week view and show some things inside. So it will have a header which is the date and additional a list of persons which have their birthday on this date.
My approach was to use a GridView for showing each day of the week and inside the data template of the GridView I'd like to show a ListView of the list of persons.

My code looks like this:

1) the data stored within is an observable collection:

```
public class WeekView
{
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int MaxTemperature { get; set; }
    public int MinTemperature { get; set; }
    public string TemperatureIcon { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CalendarItem> BirthdayList { get; set; }

    public WeekView(System.DateTime date, int v1, int v2, string temperatureIcon, ObservableCollection<CalendarItem> birthdayList)
    {
       this.Date = date;
       this.MaxTemperature = v1;
       this.MinTemperature = v2;
       this.TemperatureIcon = temperatureIcon;
       this.BirthdayList = birthdayList;
    }        
}
```

and the BirthdayList is another ObservableCollection with similar structure.

2) my user control looks like this (for easier understanding I've removed some formating stuff here):

```
<Grid>
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="360" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDayNameConverter}, FallbackValue=Donnerstag}" 
                                   Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateStringConverter}, FallbackValue='16. Februar 2016'}" 
                               Grid.Column="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TemperatureIcon}" 
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MaxTemperatureIcon"    
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="&#xf055;">
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaxTemperature, FallbackValue='23°C'}" 
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="1">                                            
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MinTemperatureIcon"    
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="0">
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MinTemperature, FallbackValue='15°C'}" 
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="1">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="BirthdayListView" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BirthdayList.BirthdayString}" 
                                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BirthdayList.NameString}" 
                                               Grid.Column="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,0"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

3) I'm binding the date to the GridView Item using the following code:

```
this.WeekView1.DataContext = this.WeekViewModel.WeekViewList1;
```

whereby `WeekViewList1` is type of `ObservableCollection<WeekView>`

Showing the elements Date and weather works (so the basic grid view works), but how can I bind the BirthdayList to the ListView inside the GridView?

Comment: `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BirthdayList}" ...>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataContext of an item in the GridView will be the corresponding `WeekView` object so as suggested by @Aybe in the comments you should bind the ItemsSource property of the ListView to the BirthdayList property of the `WeekView`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BirthdayList}" x:Name="BirthdayListView">
...
```

The DataContext of an item in the inner "BirthdayListView" will then be a `CalendarItem` object so you should bind the TextBlocks in its DataTemplate to properties of the `CalendarItem` class.

Assuming that both "BirthdayString" and "NameString" are properties of the `CalendarItem` type the bindings should look like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BirthdayList}" x:Name="BirthdayListView" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BirthdayString}" 
                                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameString}" 
                                               Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```